# Is it possible to access the XAMPP on vmware workstation?

Tags: vmware, xampp

I have Ubuntu 10.10 and installed XAMPP on it. Also I have Windows 7 installed via VMware Workstation 7.1.3.

I do my delelopment work on Ubuntu.

I want to use IE-Tester for testing on all versions of Internet explorer.

I access my site in Ubuntu as `http://localhost/mysite`

My question is ...... Is it possible for me to see the output of this site in the Windows 7 installation of vmware workstation? If yes How?

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you access it depends on the network settings on the virtual machine. If you use NAT, you should get an IP address, that would make it possible to access the machine. On my setup, I have set the connection to NAT.

*Share the Mac's connection (NAT)*, is it called on my mac. You should have very similar option.

Using this setting, I am able to get a local IP address, where I can access the server. Im my case i is 192.168.140.137.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes I am using NAT but how do I find the IP of Ubunto and how do I connect? Kindly help.

Comment: In Ubuntu, you can find the IP address, in the Network Tools utility (_System->Administration->Network tools_), and selecting Ethernet Interface `eth0`. In the IP-Address field, you'll see the ip on the second row.
You may also open up a terminal, and type `ifconfig`, and you'll see the ip address on the network interfaces eth0, (inet addr: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx).